# How much upkeep for portable Tri-Fuel generators

Tags: generator

A PM site says whole house generators need considerable upkeep:
"After 24 to 48 hours of continuous use, get it serviced, installer ... says. After around 10 days, have a professional change the oil and the filter."
http://www.popularmechanics.com/home/how-to/a8523/should-you-buy-a-standby-generator-14880060/

My question is: Do portable tri-fuel generators require similarly frequent upkeep?

Comment: A brief search of some tri-fuel users manuals online, shows that they all require service that I would consider typical of any intermittent-use internal combustion engine with a carburetor. It's always good to ask questions, but it's also sometimes helpful to do some research on your own. Do you have a goal you're trying to accomplish? I've seen several questions from your pop up regarding tri-fuel generators.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk  I am trying to decide whether to buy a "whole house" nat gas generator, a portable tri-fuel, or a gasoline generator.  I've had a gasoline generator in the past, 5,000watt.  Buying gas can be difficult during outages.  Gas generators start and run easily.  Nat gas avoids the need to buy gasoline.  But there are tradeoffs.  Nat gas generators cost more and seem more temperamental-sensitive to gas pressure. I am trying to anticipate problems w each approach before buying.  The PM caution to service so frequently sent up red flags.  Do you think they were being over cautious?

Comment: I'm not sure about over cautious, I think they may have been following manufacturer's recommendation. Have you looked into a hard-plumbed natural gas or propane generator? Some of these can be run off of a propane tank like you'd have for a grill.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk  A Briggs&Strat manual for a small whole house generator says change spark plugs every 100 Hours or Annually (http://bsintek.basco.com/BriggsDocumentDisplay/gfntCFXBnfBhU7y.pdf). That seems like a lot of maintenance!

Comment: I guess I only find things like "change main bearings" to be a lot of maintenance. With a good socket set, this should be a 12 minute job.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk  Why do spark plugs in an auto last a year and in a home generator they only last a WEEK?

Comment: Great question, I would try the automotive stack exchange. However it's worth pointing out, my dad has yet to change the spark plugs in the honda engine in his 12 year old Husqvarna Pro push mower...still starts first pull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This answer will be more generalized, than specific to generators. Also, I have a small engine repair and service certification from Briggs and Stratton.

All internal combustion engines will need regular service several systems. The most common of which are:

- Lubricants
- Air Filter
- Fuel Delivery
- Ignition

These things needing service will have vastly differing service schedules, depending on things like their duty/use types, sophistication of manufacturing, fuel deliver (carburation v. fuel injection (wet) v. direct fuel injection), type of fuel, age of motor, effectiveness of seals and so on.

For instance, it's not uncommon for a modern, fuel injected car motor, to safely go 5000-7000 miles before needing an oil change, and might go nearly 100k miles on single set of spark plugs (my wife's old CRV).

However, for things like generators that get only intermittent use, these problems follow a different schedule, that will be unique to that motor and schedule of use. Only being used perhaps once a year, makes generators particularly difficult to maintain and diagnose problems, since you may only find it when you need to use the generator. Many fixed installation generators remedy this with a weekly test run cycle, and built in diagnostics.

Liquid fuels like kerosene, gasoline, ethanol, and diesel all have different degrees and problems that can plague them, mainly in storage. Water in fuel, and evaporation of fuel is especially a problem for carbureted motors, which are effectively open systems. Thankfully, this is eliminated (mostly) in fuel injection systems, which are not open to the atmosphere, subject to evaporation.

Moving to a gaseous fuel (propane, natural gas, etc) similarly has much less of a problem (if none at all) with this issue with evaporation and deposition of the heavier components. However, liquid fuels usually provide some degree of lubrication to things like valves, and to a less extent the piston in the block. A gaseous fuel has no/negligible lubrication properties.

TL:DR All engines require service. Gas powered require the least maintenance, but can be more expensive initially.

Personal Suggestion: Go to a fixed installation generator on gaseous fuel, automatic cut-over on power failure, hopefully having automatic diagnostics and a regular self test cycle. Then you just change the air filter and oil when it tells you to.

Comment: Yes, we've been spoiled with the newer cars' sparse maintenance schedules. I've taken the DIY advice to check the manuals (online). One Honda manual says to change the oil every 20 hours of use (http://cdn.powerequipment.honda.com/pe/pdf/manuals/00X31ZT76310.pdf).  That is so much more often (daily!) than every 7,000 mile!  Thanks for opening my eyes to the extreme difference in PMS for small engines.

Comment: You're very welcome. Also, as a side note, if you feel like taking the chance, you *could* deviate from that schedule depending on use. It's not uncommon to stick to changing the oil once per year/season, while just "topping up" if the oil is low between uses. Same thing goes for spark plugs. If it starts and runs clean, once per year is probably ok.